# how to received "Accept" header in REST web service server side

Tags: java, web-services, rest, request, request-headers

i have write a REST web service in java.But If I want to receive `Accept : application/json` header ,how to do that?If I want to receive more custom header like "CDMI-Speciation-1.0" , how can i receive both headers?

My web service is like that:

```
@PUT
@Consumes("application/json")
@Produces("application/json")
public vodi doPut(){.....}
```

My request should be like : `curl --header "Content-Type:application/json" --header` `Accept:application/json" --header "CDMI-Specification-1.0" http://localhost/user -v`

What I know is `@Conusmes` is for "Content-Type" .Is it?

thanks

Comment: Yes, `Consumes` is for the Content-Type of the request, and `Produces` is for the Accept of the request, and the Content-Type of the response.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are annotations that can retrieve the http headers, for example:

```
@PUT
@Consumes("application/json")
@Produces("application/json")
public void doPut(@Context HttpHeaders hh){
    .....
}
```

You can also retrieve a single header:

```
@PUT
@Consumes("application/json")
@Produces("application/json")
public void doPut(@HeaderParam("Accept") acceptHeader){
    .....
}
```

See [here](https://wikis.oracle.com/display/Jersey/Overview+of+JAX-RS+1.0+Features) for more information.