# How do I get the @RolesAllowed annotation to work for my Web application?

Tags: java, security, ejb, jax-rs, resteasy

I am making a Web application using Backbone.js, Bootstrap, NetBeans IDE 8.0, Java EE 7, JDK 8, WildFly server 8.1.0, JBoss RESTEasy (resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.8), JBoss 2.2.22, JBoss EJB 3.

I am (relatively) new to Web development, and as such I have only just started to grasp a lot of basic concepts and technologies. I am trying to build a permission system with users and roles into a Web application, but I cannot seem to make the *@RolesAllowed annotation* to work in my RESTful Web Service. I am already working on this problem for a few days.

I have a RESTful resource (Java Enterprise/Session Bean?) called *UserResource.java*, in here I have a method *create* to create a new user for the application:

```
import java.net.URI;
import java.security.Principal;
import java.util.List;
import javax.annotation.security.PermitAll;
import javax.annotation.security.RolesAllowed;
import javax.ejb.EJB;
import javax.ejb.Stateless;
import javax.ws.rs.*;
import javax.ws.rs.core.*;
import org.jboss.ejb3.annotation.SecurityDomain;

@Stateless
@SecurityDomain("other")
@Path("/user")
public class UserResource {
    @EJB(name = "UserServiceImp")
    UserService userService;

    @Context
    private UriInfo uriInfo;

    @RolesAllowed({"admin"})
    @Path("create")
    @POST
    public Response create(CreateRequest request) {        
        try {
            System.out.println("Start of create method");
            User user = userService.createUser(request);
            return getCreateResponse(user);
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            return Response.status(401).entity("Failed to create user").build();
        }
    }
}
```

This *create* method works if I use the @PermitAll annotation, but it fails with an error if I use the @RolesAllowed annotation.

I have this Backbone view *CreateUserView* which provides a form (in HTML) to an end user (with admin rights) for creating new users for the application. On clicking the submit button, JSON data gets send to the url 'rest/user/create' for creating a new user. Before the *create* method in *UserResource.java* gets executed, my *SecurityInterceptor.java* (which implements *javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerRequestFilter*) checks if the user has the required permissions. I have debugged this thorough and the Security Interceptor is functioning as it should. So after the Security Interceptor gives clear access, something goes wrong in *UserResource.java*. (As a side note, not sure if this is important, but I believe the Security Interceptor is based on [this blog post about RESTEasy security](http://howtodoinjava.com/2013/07/25/jax-rs-2-0-resteasy-3-0-2-final-security-tutorial/). I was working on the application with another guy, he initially implemented it, so I'm not sure.. but it looks almost identical. Anyway that guy has moved on to another project a few weeks ago.)

The error I am getting (output from the server) is the following:

```
16:45:25,775 ERROR [org.jboss.as.ejb3.invocation] (default task-60) JBAS014134: EJB Invocation failed on component UserResource for method public javax.ws.rs.core.Response org.profit.pgb.rest.resource.UserResource.create(org.profit.pgb.rest.api.CreateRequest): javax.ejb.EJBAccessException: JBAS014502: Invocation on method: public javax.ws.rs.core.Response org.profit.pgb.rest.resource.UserResource.create(org.profit.pgb.rest.api.CreateRequest) of bean: UserResource is not allowed
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.security.AuthorizationInterceptor.processInvocation(AuthorizationInterceptor.java:135) [wildfly-ejb3-8.1.0.Final.jar:8.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.security.SecurityContextInterceptor.processInvocation(SecurityContextInterceptor.java:95) [wildfly-ejb3-8.1.0.Final.jar:8.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.ShutDownInterceptorFactory$1.processInvocation(ShutDownInterceptorFactory.java:64) [wildfly-ejb3-8.1.0.Final.jar:8.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.LoggingInterceptor.processInvocation(LoggingInterceptor.java:59) [wildfly-ejb3-8.1.0.Final.jar:8.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.NamespaceContextInterceptor.processInvocation(NamespaceContextInterceptor.java:50)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.AdditionalSetupInterceptor.processInvocation(AdditionalSetupInterceptor.java:55) [wildfly-ejb3-8.1.0.Final.jar:8.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)
    at org.jboss.invocation.ContextClassLoaderInterceptor.processInvocation(ContextClassLoaderInterceptor.java:64)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.run(InterceptorContext.java:326)
    at org.wildfly.security.manager.WildFlySecurityManager.doChecked(WildFlySecurityManager.java:448)
    at org.jboss.invocation.AccessCheckingInterceptor.processInvocation(AccessCheckingInterceptor.java:61)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.run(InterceptorContext.java:326)
    at org.jboss.invocation.PrivilegedWithCombinerInterceptor.processInvocation(PrivilegedWithCombinerInterceptor.java:80)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)
    at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ViewService$View.invoke(ViewService.java:185)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ViewDescription$1.processInvocation(ViewDescription.java:182)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)
    at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ProxyInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyInvocationHandler.java:73)
    at org.profit.pgb.rest.resource.UserResource$$$view45.create(Unknown Source) [classes:]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.8.0_11]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) [rt.jar:1.8.0_11]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) [rt.jar:1.8.0_11]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483) [rt.jar:1.8.0_11]
    at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.Reflections.invokeAndUnwrap(Reflections.java:401) [weld-core-impl-2.1.2.Final.jar:2014-01-09 09:23]
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.EnterpriseBeanProxyMethodHandler.invoke(EnterpriseBeanProxyMethodHandler.java:99) [weld-core-impl-2.1.2.Final.jar:2014-01-09 09:23]
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.EnterpriseTargetBeanInstance.invoke(EnterpriseTargetBeanInstance.java:56) [weld-core-impl-2.1.2.Final.jar:2014-01-09 09:23]
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.InjectionPointPropagatingEnterpriseTargetBeanInstance.invoke(InjectionPointPropagatingEnterpriseTargetBeanInstance.java:65) [weld-core-impl-2.1.2.Final.jar:2014-01-09 09:23]
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ProxyMethodHandler.invoke(ProxyMethodHandler.java:100) [weld-core-impl-2.1.2.Final.jar:2014-01-09 09:23]
    at org.profit.pgb.rest.resource.UserResource$Proxy$_$$_Weld$EnterpriseProxy$.create(Unknown Source) [classes:]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.8.0_11]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) [rt.jar:1.8.0_11]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) [rt.jar:1.8.0_11]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483) [rt.jar:1.8.0_11]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.MethodInjectorImpl.invoke(MethodInjectorImpl.java:137) [resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.8.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invokeOnTarget(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:296) [resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.8.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:250) [resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.8.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:237) [resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.8.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:356) [resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.8.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:179) [resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.8.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ServletContainerDispatcher.service(ServletContainerDispatcher.java:220) [resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.8.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:56) [resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.8.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:51) [resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.8.Final.jar:]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790) [jboss-servlet-api_3.1_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:85) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:61) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:25) [undertow-core-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:113) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:56) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:25) [undertow-core-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationConstraintHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationConstraintHandler.java:51) [undertow-core-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:45) [undertow-core-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:61) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityConstraintHandler.java:56) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:58) [undertow-core-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:70) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.SecurityInitialHandler.handleRequest(SecurityInitialHandler.java:76) [undertow-core-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:25) [undertow-core-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:25) [undertow-core-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:25) [undertow-core-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:240) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:227) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:73) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:146) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:177) [undertow-core-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:727) [undertow-core-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [rt.jar:1.8.0_11]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [rt.jar:1.8.0_11]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.8.0_11]

16:45:25,957 ERROR [io.undertow.request] (default task-60) UT005023: Exception handling request to /pgb/rest/user/create: org.jboss.resteasy.spi.UnhandledException: javax.ejb.EJBAccessException: JBAS014502: Invocation on method: public javax.ws.rs.core.Response org.profit.pgb.rest.resource.UserResource.create(org.profit.pgb.rest.api.CreateRequest) of bean: UserResource is not allowed
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ExceptionHandler.handleApplicationException(ExceptionHandler.java:76) [resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.8.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ExceptionHandler.handleException(ExceptionHandler.java:212) [resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.8.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.writeException(SynchronousDispatcher.java:149) [resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.8.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:372) [resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.8.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:179) [resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.8.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ServletContainerDispatcher.service(ServletContainerDispatcher.java:220) [resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.8.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:56) [resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.8.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:51) [resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.8.Final.jar:]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790) [jboss-servlet-api_3.1_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:85) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:61) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:25) [undertow-core-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:113) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:56) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:25) [undertow-core-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationConstraintHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationConstraintHandler.java:51) [undertow-core-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:45) [undertow-core-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:61) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityConstraintHandler.java:56) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:58) [undertow-core-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:70) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.SecurityInitialHandler.handleRequest(SecurityInitialHandler.java:76) [undertow-core-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:25) [undertow-core-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:25) [undertow-core-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:25) [undertow-core-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:240) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:227) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:73) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:146) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:177) [undertow-core-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:727) [undertow-core-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [rt.jar:1.8.0_11]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [rt.jar:1.8.0_11]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.8.0_11]
Caused by: javax.ejb.EJBAccessException: JBAS014502: Invocation on method: public javax.ws.rs.core.Response org.profit.pgb.rest.resource.UserResource.create(org.profit.pgb.rest.api.CreateRequest) of bean: UserResource is not allowed
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.security.AuthorizationInterceptor.processInvocation(AuthorizationInterceptor.java:135) [wildfly-ejb3-8.1.0.Final.jar:8.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.security.SecurityContextInterceptor.processInvocation(SecurityContextInterceptor.java:95) [wildfly-ejb3-8.1.0.Final.jar:8.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.ShutDownInterceptorFactory$1.processInvocation(ShutDownInterceptorFactory.java:64) [wildfly-ejb3-8.1.0.Final.jar:8.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)
    at ... etc. (not fully shown due to SO's character limit on questions..)
```

I've seen other people ask similar questions, some which remain unanswered to this day (e.g. [jax-rs service RolesAllowed Annotation throwing exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19863311/jax-rs-service-rolesallowed-annotation-throwing-exception)) and others which have solutions that either do not work for me or maybe I do not apply the solution correctly (e.g. [RESTEasy support for JAX-RS @RolesAllowed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24591782/resteasy-support-for-jax-rs-rolesallowed)).

I found this: https://developer.jboss.org/thread/177728?start=0&tstart=0 (titled: *"@RolesAllowed, @DenyAll require presence of org.jboss.ejb3.annotation.SecurityDomain?"*), In tried the solution but I cannot get it to work for my project. Not sure if the solution is not applicable for my situation or if I'm just doing it wrong.

I found this: https://developer.jboss.org/message/720815 (titled: *"is this a defect for processing org.jboss.ejb3.annotation.SecurityDomain ?"*), but I do not understand where my *jboss-ejb-client.properties* are supposed to be. I think they set their project up quite different from me. So no luck with that.

I found [a guide on EJB3 security](https://github.com/jboss-eap/quickstart/tree/master-eap6/ejb-security), as suggested there, I provided the following code in my *standalone.xml*-file:

```
<security-domain name="other" cache-type="default">
    <authentication>
        <login-module code="Remoting" flag="optional">
            <module-option name="password-stacking" value="useFirstPass"/>
        </login-module>
        <login-module code="RealmDirect" flag="required">
            <module-option name="password-stacking" value="useFirstPass"/>
        </login-module>
    </authentication>
</security-domain>
```

But that did not solve anything at all. I am not sure if it did anything.

Finally, I found this SO question: [RESTEasy support for JAX-RS @RolesAllowed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24591782/resteasy-support-for-jax-rs-rolesallowed) (which references to the [RESTEasy Documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/3.0.5.Final/userguide/html/Securing_JAX-RS_and_RESTeasy.html)). Even though I also mentioned this question a few paragraphs up as containing a solution that does not work for me, it did change the error to another error. As suggested there I added a *<context-param>*-block to my *web.xml*-file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
    <security-constraint>
        <web-resource-collection>
            <web-resource-name>PGB</web-resource-name>
            <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
            <http-method>GET</http-method>
            <http-method>POST</http-method>
        </web-resource-collection>

        <user-data-constraint>
            <!-- use of SSL is required when CONFIDENTIAL is specified -->
            <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
        </user-data-constraint>
    </security-constraint>

    <context-param>
      <param-name>resteasy.role.based.security</param-name>
      <param-value>true</param-value>
   </context-param>
</web-app>
```

Which results in the following error if I try to create a new user (not completely posted here due to character limit of SO questions):

```
16:58:45,992 WARN  [org.jboss.resteasy.core.ExceptionHandler] (default task-61) failed to execute: javax.ws.rs.ForbiddenException: HTTP 403 Forbidden
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.interceptors.RoleBasedSecurityFilter.filter(RoleBasedSecurityFilter.java:45) [resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.8.Final.jar:]
    at ... etc.
```

This error is not very helpful either, in fact, I find even less information when I search on that error than when I search on the previous error. So, I am not sure if that is a step into the right direction. What is better to have returned from the server? A status 500 (Internal Server Error) or a status 403 (Forbidden)? Also, if after applying that "solution" I change the annotation to @PermitAll, then the creation of a new user works just as before, so it didn't really make the situation any worse.

However, I can find [the source code of RoleBasedSecurityFilter](https://github.com/resteasy/Resteasy/blob/master/jaxrs/resteasy-jaxrs/src/main/java/org/jboss/resteasy/plugins/interceptors/RoleBasedSecurityFilter.java), which shows that it throws the `ForbiddenException`. It shows that a certain *isUserInRole* method must return true, but it does not do that in my application. I can't get it to return true. It makes me wonder, [Is it possible to disable RoleBasedSecurityFilter.java of RESTEasy?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26039920/2541501)

I also found the following SO question: [@RolesAllowed cannot be resolved with Jersey](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15188895/rolesallowed-cannot-be-resolved-with-jersey), which is answered by Abhijit Sarkar, and he refers to [an IBM article](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.multiplatform.doc/ae/twbs_jaxrs_impl_securejaxrs_webcont.html?cp=SSAW57_8.5.5%2F3-3-0-42-3-0). Maybe the solution to my problem lies in there, but I have not found it yet.. Anyway, it is suggested there that either adding a *security-role* block to my *web.xml*-file or adding a *@DeclareRoles* annotation to my *UserResource.java* file should solve the problem, but the HTTP 403 Forbidden warning still remains after I do so. It is very frustrating.

My *security-role* block (in web.xml) looks as follows:

```
<security-role id="role_admin">
    <description>This is role 1 (admin)</description>
    <role-name>admin</role-name>
</security-role>
```

And I added the following *security-constraint* block (in web.xml): (note the *auth-constraint*)

```
<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>PGB</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/rest/user/create</url-pattern>
        <http-method>GET</http-method>
        <http-method>POST</http-method>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint id="AuthConstraint_createUser">
        <description> Only admin can create a new user</description>
        <role-name>admin</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
    <user-data-constraint>
        <!-- use of SSL is required when CONFIDENTIAL is specified -->
        <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
    </user-data-constraint>
</security-constraint>
```

I realize now that my problem lies either in the deployment descriptors (*web.xml*) or the server configuration (WildFly's *standalone-full.xml*).

I added a `login-config` element (with [FORM authentication](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19798-01/821-1841/bncbn/index.html)) to my *web.xml* file. Changed my login HTML page to fit [the required format](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19798-01/821-1841/bncca/index.html). I followed some of the step of this article on [migrating a Java EE App from GlassFish to WildFly](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19798-01/821-1841/bncca/index.html), but I think I still did something wrong because I always get at the login error page when trying to log in with valid user credentials.

See here the `security-domain` element I added to my WildFly configuration:

```
<security-domain name="app" cache-type="default">
    <authentication>
        <login-module code="Database" flag="required">
            <module-option name="dsJndiName" value="java:jboss/datasources/mySQL_pool_rel"/>
            <module-option name="principalsQuery" value="select hashed_password from user where email_address=?"/>
            <module-option name="rolesQuery" value="select role_name, 'Roles' from role r inner join user u on r.role_type = u.role_type where u.email_address = ?"/>
            <module-option name="hashAlgorithm" value="SHA-256"/>
            <module-option name="hashEncoding" value="BASE64"/>
            <module-option name="unauthenticatedIdentity" value="guest"/>
        </login-module>
        <login-module code="RoleMapping" flag="required">
             <module-option name="rolesProperties" value="file:${jboss.server.config.dir}/app.properties"/>
             <module-option name="replaceRole" value="false"/>
        </login-module>
    </authentication>
</security-domain>
```

I think something is wrong with my *rolesQuery* defined there, but I can't figure out what.

I would love to know how to implement role-based security for my Web application. Therefore, I also accept other approaches to role-based security, as long as it works. Suggestions are welcome.

I also placed [my question on developer.jboss.org](https://developer.jboss.org/thread/248877), but I also got no response there yet.

I provided one workaround solution to my problem as an answer to this question, but it is not a real solution (as explained in that answer). I am still interested in doing this the right way.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Just had the same problem.

It's the `@Stateless` annotation. The marks your class as an EJB and the container attempts to enforce EJB security.

I discovered this by writing filters and my own SecurityContext, only to find that my `SecurityContext` was never referenced.

Removing `@Stateless` resulted in `getUserPrincipal()` being called on the `SecurityContext`.

Comment: If we remove the Stateless annotation then how are we going to use it as a stateless bean. Just confused. there has to be some there way as well.I am having the same issue and it seems that the getUserPrincipal is not called when invoking the EJB.

Comment: Break rest class into rest and business. business shall be stateless only and it will be called from rest.

Answer (score 4):

Based on the error "403", it seems to me that there is something wrong with your role query. Maybe, your login module doesn't assign "admin" role to your user. One thing you could do is implement a custom authentication mechanism http://undertow.io/undertow-docs/undertow-docs-1.3.0/#authentication-mechanisms (example: https://github.com/dstraub/spnego-wildfly), and modify it in such a way that you could check which roles your login module assigns to your user. Implementing custom authentication mechanism is going to take you some time, but it helps you understand better how security works in wildfly.

Other thing I had to do for my Roles annotation to work is modify standalone.xml and set your security-domain as the default one.

Also, adding those lines is a step in the right direction, as for me. Without those lines annotations @RolesAllowed don't work for me.

```xml
<context-param>
    <param-name>resteasy.role.based.security</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>
```

Also, I would advice implementing security using web.xml only, and only after that is done, try adding @RolesAllowed.

Answer (score 3):

I found one solution to my problem. However, this isn't as much a solution to the problem as it is a `workaround`, because it does not use the *@RolesAllowed* annotation.

Since I was unable to figure out how to define my deployment descriptors and server configuration exactly, I figured the problem would be solved much easier if I simply did not use the *@RolesAllowed* annotation.

Even though other people might really want to use the `login-config` element in their *web.xml* file and not use any other means of authentication, this approach does not use that element but instead does authentication solely through [RESTful Web Services](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gijqy.html) (which means that nothing needs to change in the deployment descriptors or the server configuration).

I created a new *Enterprise Java Bean (EJB)* called `SecurityFilter` which checks if a user has the required roles for certain functionalities. It is implemented as follows:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;
import javax.ejb.EJB;
import javax.ejb.Stateless;
import javax.ws.rs.core.HttpHeaders;
import org.profit.pgb.rest.user.UserService;

@Stateless
public class SecurityFilter
{
    @EJB(name = "UserServiceImp")
    UserService userService;

    public boolean isUserAllowed (String[] rolesArray, HttpHeaders hHeaders)
    {
        Set<String> rolesSet = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(rolesArray));

        String uuid = hHeaders.getRequestHeader("user").get(0);
        String token = hHeaders.getRequestHeader("token").get(0);

        if (userService.isAuthorizationTokenValid(uuid, token))
        {
           if (userService.isUserAllowed(uuid, rolesSet))
           {
               return true; // user allowed access
           }
        }   
        return false; // 401
    }
}
```

The method *isUserAllowed* is called in the *create* method of *UserResource.java*. The old implementation of this *create* method can be seen in the question above. The new implementation is as follows:

```
@PermitAll
@Path("create")
@POST
public Response create(CreateRequest request, @Context HttpHeaders hHeaders) {  
    if (securityFilter.isUserAllowed(new String[]{"admin"}, hHeaders))
    {
        try {
            System.out.println("Start of create method");
            User user = userService.createUser(request);
            return getCreateResponse(user);
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            return Response.status(401).entity("Failed to create user").build();
        }
    }
    else
        return Response.status(401).entity("Access denied! User does not have permission to create user").build();
}
```

As you can see, an if-else statement replaces the *@RolesAllowed* annotation in this approach and my security filter is implemented slightly different.

Also, this approach uses [HttpHeaders](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ws/rs/core/HttpHeaders.html) to get the request headers (in which the user ID and token are stored). [The accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6504062/2541501) on the SO question "[how to received "Accept" header in REST web service server side](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6503960/how-to-received-accept-header-in-rest-web-service-server-side/6504062#6504062)" helped me find [how to get the request headers](https://wikis.oracle.com/display/Jersey/Overview+of+JAX-RS+1.0+Features).

Furthermore, this approach works without changing anything in my *Backbone.js*- and *Bootstrap*-based web pages (i.e. my HTML and JavaScript files).

Answer (score 0):

I saw your post on my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20025434/839733). I'm not very familiar with JBoss proprietary security, neither do I recommend having it embedded in the code, but I guess that's not my problem. From your code, I don't see `security-role` or `@DeclareRoles` present; it is clearly mentioned in my answer that you need either one for annotation-based security to work. DId you exclude that for brevity or did you miss it? In case of the later, add `@DeclareRoles` to `UserResource` class and see if that helps.

Comment: Thanks for taking your time to help me out. Ah yes sorry for that, I did try both `security-role` and `@DeclareRoles`, but no matter what I do it still results in a `javax.ws.rs.ForbiddenException: HTTP 403 Forbidden` warning. I excluded that for brevity, but on second thought it might be an important detail to include in my question. Also, what kind of security do you recommend? (as opposed to "having it embedded in the code")

Comment: Your problem appears to be between JBoss security config and web container. Your `web.xml` as shown above doesn't have a `login-config` element without which the web container has no way to know who you're. I'd recommend that you go back to the basics, ditch the EJB and just try to get a simple POJO JAX-RS service working with declarative security. Then you can incrementally build on it.
Here's a [working example](https://github.com/abhijitsarkar/java-ee/tree/master/webservices/jax-rs/jaxrs-security/calculator-decl) using GlassFish from my github. You should be able to port it to JBoss.

Comment: Sorry to add 2 comments but couldn't help it due to the character limit on comments. You asked what'd I recommend instead of having JBoss proprietary annotation in the code. My preference would be to externalize any vendor-specific configuration in XML deployment descriptors. In the link that I gave in my previous comment, you can see I did that using a GF specific DD `glassfish-web.xml`. HTH.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. Ah I didn't realize the `login-config` element was required, but it does make sense now. I think I can get it to work by adding `login-config` and updating my deployment descriptors. I think it wouldn't be too hard to port your example to JBoss/WildFly (for example see [this](http://wildfly.org/news/2014/02/06/GlassFish-to-WildFly-migration/)). I will update here when I implemented a fully functional role-based security system for my Web application.

Answer (score 0):

You need to basically access the ejb from a web client

You need to add the following code to web.xml

```
<login-config>
    <auth-method>BASIC</auth-method>
    <realm-name>ManagementRealm</realm-name>
</login-config>
```

You need to add the following code to standalone.xml

```
 <security-domain name="other" cache-type="default">
                <authentication>
                    <login-module code="Remoting" flag="optional">
                        <module-option name="password-stacking" value="useFirstPass"/>
                    </login-module>
        <login-module code="RealmUsersRoles" flag="required">
                        <module-option name="usersProperties" value="${jboss.server.config.dir}/application-users.properties"/>
                        <module-option name="rolesProperties" value="${jboss.server.config.dir}/application-roles.properties"/>
                        <module-option name="realm" value="ApplicationRealm"/>
                        <module-option name="password-stacking" value="useFirstPass"/>
                </login-module>
                    <login-module code="RealmDirect" flag="required">
                        <module-option name="password-stacking" value="useFirstPass"/>
                    </login-module>
                </authentication>
            </security-domain>
```

You can easily create an ejb bean and an ejb interface in an EJBproject

Then you can access this ejb from a web project using a servlet
My servlet looks as follows:

```
@WebServlet("/JbossServlet")
public class JbossServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
       
    @EJB
    Calculator1 calculator1;
        
    public JbossServlet() {}
    
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {     
        System.out.println("1 + 1 = " + calculator1.add(1, 1));
        System.out.println("1 - 1 = " + calculator1.subtract(1, 1));
        System.out.println("4/2 = " + calculator1.divide(4, 2));
    }

    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        doGet(request, response);
    }   

}

Don't forget to create an application user using jboss-cli.bat before accessing it from the url
    
My EJB3 bean looks as follows:

package org.jboss.tutorial.stateless.bean;

import java.security.Principal;

import javax.annotation.Resource;
import javax.annotation.security.PermitAll;
import javax.annotation.security.RolesAllowed;
import javax.ejb.Remote;
import javax.ejb.SessionContext;
import javax.ejb.Stateful;
import javax.ejb.TransactionAttribute;
import javax.ejb.TransactionAttributeType;


import org.jboss.logging.Logger;
import org.jboss.security.annotation.SecurityDomain;


@Stateful
@Remote(Calculator1.class)
@SecurityDomain("Other")
public class CalculatorBean1 implements Calculator1 {
    private static Logger log = Logger.getLogger(CalculatorBean1.class.getName());

      @Resource
      private SessionContext ctx;

      
       @PermitAll
       @TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRES_NEW)
       public int add(Integer x, Integer y)
       {
           log.info("ctx"+ctx);
          return x + y;
       }
       
       @RolesAllowed({"admin"})
       public int subtract(Integer x, Integer y)
       {
           log.info("inside subtract");
           boolean callerInRole=ctx.isCallerInRole("admin");
           Principal callerPrincipal = ctx.getCallerPrincipal();
           String callerKey = callerPrincipal.getName();
           log.info("callerPrincipal"+callerPrincipal);
           log.info("callerKey"+callerKey);
           log.info("callerInRole"+callerInRole);
           log.info("nt isCallerInRole('RoleOne'): " + callerInRole);
           log.info("nnt CalculatorBean  subtract() called...substract= "+(x-y));
             return x - y;
       }
       
       @RolesAllowed({"admin"})
       public Integer divide(Integer x, Integer y)
       {
           log.info("inside divide");
           boolean callerInRole=ctx.isCallerInRole("RoleTwo");
           log.info("nt isCallerInRole('RoleTwo'): " + callerInRole);
           log.info("nnt CalculatorBean  divide() called...divide= "+(x/y));
              return x / y;
       }
}
    
My EJB3 interface looks as follows:    
    
    

 package org.jboss.tutorial.stateless.bean;
    
 import javax.ejb.Remote;
    
    @Remote
    public interface Calculator1 {
        public int add(Integer a, Integer b);
        public int subtract(Integer a, Integer b);
        public Integer divide(Integer x, Integer y);
    }
```

Comment: For further reference please refer the following url:   https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/jboss_enterprise_application_platform/6.1/html/security_guide/about_the_structure_of_the_security_subsystem