# Is it possible to disable RoleBasedSecurityFilter.java of RESTEasy?

Tags: java, security, rest, jboss, resteasy

I am developing a Web application which uses JBoss RESTEasy (resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.8) but I want to disable the [RoleBasedSecurityFilter.java](https://github.com/resteasy/Resteasy/blob/master/jaxrs/resteasy-jaxrs/src/main/java/org/jboss/resteasy/plugins/interceptors/RoleBasedSecurityFilter.java) and only use my own custom `SecurityInterceptor` class (which also implements `javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerRequestFilter` just as the `RoleBasedSecurityFilter` class does, so they are both security filters).

The reason for this is that [line 43](https://github.com/resteasy/Resteasy/blob/master/jaxrs/resteasy-jaxrs/src/main/java/org/jboss/resteasy/plugins/interceptors/RoleBasedSecurityFilter.java#L43) in *RoleBasedSecurityFilter.java* calls a [isUserInRole() method](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ws/rs/core/SecurityContext.html#isUserInRole(java.lang.String)), which always returns false in my application. And as result a *ForbiddenException* gets thrown, which prevents the user from accessing resources he should have access to.

I really like being able to use the [@RolesAllowed annotation](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/annotation/security/RolesAllowed.html) to declare which roles have access to certain functionalities, but as explained, the *RoleBasedSecurityFilter* class is blocking this. So my question is, does anyone know how to disable one specific RESTEasy filter (i.e. *RoleBasedSecurityFilter*)?

I'd imagine that it might be done in the deployment descriptor (web.xml) (for example with a [context-param element](http://www.factorypattern.com/storing-parameters-in-webxml-context-param-init-param/)), but I have no clue how to actually disable the filter.

I realize I could also change the line in the *RoleBasedSecurityFilter.java* file in the RESTEasy library I am using, but that approach is too hacky for me as I don't want to be stuck having to apply this hack again everytime I would upgrade my RESTEasy version. (not sure how often that would be though..)

Answer (score 0):

You can enable / disable the role based security by adding this configuration in the web.inf deployment descriptor.

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>resteasy.role.based.security</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I am aware I can disable **all** RESTEasy role-based security by setting that value to false, but [then I get a `javax.ejb.EJBAccessException`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25851374/2541501)... anyway, I _don't_ want to disable all RESTEasy role-based security because I have my own custom `SecurityInterceptor` class (which is RESTEasy security too!) I only want to _disable one specific security filter_, namely the standard RESTEasy Security Filter (i.e. `RoleBasedSecurityFilter.java`).