# EJB Exception at startup for application migrated from JBoss AS 7.1.1 Final to JBoss Wildfly 9.0.1

Tags: ejb, jboss7.x, wildfly

I am getting the following error from an application I am migrating to JBoss Wildfly and I've Googled around an haven't been able to find this specific error.

Has anyone else seen this?

What is the cause and/or solution?

We are seeing this error in Wildfly.  We are not seeing the error in AS.

EDIT:
This error is occuring at startup.  The method is being invoked using an @Startup annotation.

```
12:43:34,442 ERROR [org.jboss.as.ejb3.invocation] (schema_update_thread) WFLYEJB0034: EJB Invocation failed on component DBSchemaUpdateBean for method public void com.mycompany.myappserver.ejb.DBSchemaUpdateBean.processUpdates(com.mycompany.myappserver.config.sql.DBType) throws java.lang.Exception: javax.ejb.EJBAccessException: WFLYEJB0364: Invocation on method: public void com.mycompany.myappserver.ejb.DBSchema
UpdateBean.processUpdates(com.mycompany.myappserver.config.sql.DBType) throws java.lang.Exception of bean: DBSchemaUpdateBean is not allowed
        at org.jboss.as.ejb3.security.AuthorizationInterceptor.processInvocation(AuthorizationInterceptor.java:134)
        at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
        at org.jboss.as.ejb3.security.SecurityContextInterceptor.processInvocation(SecurityContextInterceptor.java:100)
        at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
        at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.ShutDownInterceptorFactory$1.processInvocation(ShutDownInterceptorFactory.java:64)
        at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
        at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.LoggingInterceptor.processInvocation(LoggingInterceptor.java:66)
        at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
        at org.jboss.as.ee.component.NamespaceContextInterceptor.processInvocation(NamespaceContextInterceptor.java:50)
        at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
        at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.AdditionalSetupInterceptor.processInvocation(AdditionalSetupInterceptor.java:54)
        at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
        at org.jboss.invocation.ContextClassLoaderInterceptor.processInvocation(ContextClassLoaderInterceptor.java:64)
        at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
        at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.run(InterceptorContext.java:356)
        at org.wildfly.security.manager.WildFlySecurityManager.doChecked(WildFlySecurityManager.java:634)
        at org.jboss.invocation.AccessCheckingInterceptor.processInvocation(AccessCheckingInterceptor.java:61)
        at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
        at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.run(InterceptorContext.java:356)
        at org.jboss.invocation.PrivilegedWithCombinerInterceptor.processInvocation(PrivilegedWithCombinerInterceptor.java:80)
        at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
        at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61)
        at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ViewService$View.invoke(ViewService.java:195)
        at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ViewDescription$1.processInvocation(ViewDescription.java:185)
        at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
        at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61)
        at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ProxyInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyInvocationHandler.java:73)
        at com.mycompany.myappserver.ejb.DBSchemaUpdateBean$$$view31.processUpdates(Unknown Source)
        at com.mycompany.myappserver.ejb.SharedDataBean$1.run(SharedDataBean.java:89)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

Comment: can you post some of your code? Are you using JBoss security domain? Do you have annotations such as @RolesAllowed on your Ejbs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key part is:

> WFLYEJB0364: Invocation on method: [blah] of bean: DBSchemaUpdateBean is not allowed

JBAS014502 seems like a closely related error too (for example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25851374/how-do-i-get-the-rolesallowed-annotation-to-work-for-my-web-application)) but is mentioned more often.

Looks like `DBSchemaUpdateBean` method `processUpdates` uses a `@RolesAllowed` annotation and is being called by a client without the permitted roles. If this is happening at startup, that suggests this might be a system call during initialisation?  I suggest checking that any calls to this method during initialisation have the correct roles, and that these roles are configured properly.

Comment: Yes, this method is being called at startup using an `@Startup` annotation (I've updated the question to reflect this -- good eye and thanks for the help).  I'm not sure what user would need to be added to the `@RolesAllowed` for the startup user.  Some of the information in the link you provided suggests that this might be related to standalone.xml configuration.  There's a good chance that this might be the difference between my AS instance and my Wildfly instance as the two files are different in the two environments.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: If in doubt, you can always use `@RunAs`?

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. The presence of @RolesAllowed on the EJB and client not having the particular role results in this exception in my case. Plus you have also provided a very good link to another question.

Answer (score 5):

This was resolved by modifying the standalone xml.  This line was modified to look as it is shown below.  I'm not sure how big a security risk this represents or if there is a better way to resolve this issue.  It looks to me like this is turning off authentication (i.e. unauthenticated requests will be honored).

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:ejb3:3.0">
    ...
    <default-missing-method-permissions-deny-access value="false"/>
</subsystem>
```