# User is successfully authenticated with some roles but RolesAllowed does not accept the roles

Tags: java, servlets, jboss, ejb, saml

I work on a Java 8 application (included JBOSS, Servlet without Spring). It does the authentication with ldap. Now I have to implement SAML 2 mechanism. To implement that I used a Keycloak library ([Java Servlet filter adapter](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_single_sign-on/7.5/html/securing_applications_and_services_guide/using_saml_to_secure_applications_and_services#java-servlet-filter-adapter)). It works fine and Idp sends metadata back to my application.

After authentication the user has the expected roles and if I call the method "isUserInRole", it returns true. But @RolesAllowed does not accept the role and throws exception.

```
    @Path("/abcd")
    @GET
    public Response abcd(@Context final HttpServletRequest httpRequest) {
        httpRequest.isUserInRole("user_role");  // true
        return Response.noContent().build();
    }
```

```
@Stateless
public class MyClass {

    @RolesAllowed({"user_role"})
    public void function() {
        // ...
    }
    // javax.ejb.EJBAccessException: function is not allowed
    
}
```

I assume, RolesAllowed does not work correctly because of some old configuration from ldap, but I don't find anything.

If you have any Ideas, please write it. Thanks!

**Update:**
I noticed if I remove @Stateless, it works correctly, but that is not the solution, at least not for me. [Same problem like here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25851374/how-do-i-get-the-rolesallowed-annotation-to-work-for-my-web-application) but I don't know how to solve that.

Answer (score -1):

One gotcha is that `@RolesAllowed` will expect the user has the authority that start with the prefix `ROLE_` by default. So `@RolesAllowed({"user_role"})` will expect the user has the authority ROLE_user_role. But now since the user only has the authority `user_role`, it does not match `ROLE_user_role` and hence it is access denied.

The easy fix is change to use @PreAuthorize :

```
@GetMapping
    @PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('user_role')")
    public List<User> list(){
        return userRepository.findAll();
    }
```

It will directly check if the user has the authority user_role without any prefix behavior.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I already test the role name with prefix "ROLE_" but it does not work too. And I can not use the annotation PreAuthorize, because it is not a spring application.

Comment: The following is just my opinion:

1. Prefered way: move the pre post annotation on service layer
2. if you cannot (or do not want to), try to have your controller implement an interface containing all the annotated methods
3. as a last way, use `proxy-target-class=true`

Comment: A common problem with using PrePost annotations on controllers is that Spring method security is based on Spring AOP, which is by default implemented with JDK proxies.

That means that it works fine on the service layer which is injected in controller layer as interfaces, but it is ignored on controller layer because controller generally do not implement interfaces.